# Calculating disk speed in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, disk

Is there any cocoa API or open source library that enable me to check the disk read/write speed in OS X?

Something like what [this app](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12) (in Mac App Store) uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell, that app writes and reads a known amount of data (the user selects from 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 GB) and times how long it takes.

I imagine that the 'live' read/write times are based on a running average: "in the last 5 seconds I've written XXX MB".

I'm not aware of an API to implement something like this yourself, but you could do it fairly easily: generate a known amount of garbage (e.g. 500MB of random numbers), write it to a temporary folder, time it, do your calculations, then clean up the written data.